# How do I best optimize my paramters, choices of activation, optimizer ect. in a LSTM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, parameters

I'm training a LSTM Neural Network to predict a volatilty (timeseries) in Keras. At the moment, my network is specified as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1,1), kernel_regularizer = l2(0.0001)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=100, batch_size=16)
```

Here, I have a lot of parameters I could cross validate:

- units in LSTM?
- More layers?
- regularizer (L1 or l2, and amount)?
- Activation function?
- Optimizer?
- Batch size?

However, CV on all these parameters would result in huge computational time, so how do I determind the correct specifications for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know, doing grid-search might be the best approach. However, you can lessen your search space by examining your data. If you don't have much data, try to go for a smaller model, don't go too big (or else it will overfit). This can lessen your search space a bit. Some say less layer but more unit works well for low-resource data, but still, it is not guaranteed.

Regularizer can sometimes good or bad, it depends on the task. You'll never know if the setting is correct or not unless you experiment on it.

For batch size, it is recommended to experiment on the batch size from 16 to 512 (or you can go higher if you can). The larger the batch size is, the faster it trains, the more memory it consumes. Smaller batch size also means the model will "walk" more random. In other words, the loss will decrease at a more random pace.

For optimizer, if you want to grid search, just use Adam. It is quite good for most tasks.

All in all, no one can guarantee that tuning different hyperparameters will result in a performance gain. It all needs to be experimented and record. That's why there are so many research papers done on hyperparameters tuning.